# Installing Ubuntu packages for dummies: Gstreamer plugins to play m4a files in Clementine?

Tags: apt, package-management, sound

This is a very common question it appears, but as one who is not familiar with Linux I don't know exactly the syntax to do it.

When trying to play m4a files in Clementine, it tells me that I'm missing a Gstreamer plugin. I understand that I need to install some packages, namely `gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad` from some repository, but that's where my understanding stops. If somebody would be so kind as to show how it would be typed into the terminal (and maybe explain what's going on in each line), that would be wonderful.

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats , http://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware